# Why group by key of anonymous objects does not behave the way expected?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, anonymous-class

I have a csv file of this formart

```
 A,B,value
 a1,b1,10
 a2,b1,12
 a2,b1,15
 a2,b2,14
 a1,b1,12
```

which I am converting as datatable in my application.

```
 Dim enumerable = _dt.AsEnumerable

 Dim groupedResults = enumerable.GroupBy( _
                                   Function(x) _
                                        New With { _
                                                  .A = x.Item("A").ToString, _
                                                  .B = x.Item("B").ToString _
                                                 } _
                                        )
```

I expected the groupedResults count to 4 instead of the 5 which shows.
Basically it does not group by 1st and 5 th row into one group.

I expected object with the same value will be produce same key.

What can be the reason for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the anonymous type properties immutable - that's the way to get equality and hashing to work. (In C# all anonymous types are immutable by default.)

Try this

```
 Dim enumerable = _dt.AsEnumerable

 Dim groupedResults = enumerable.GroupBy( _
               Function(x) _
                    New With { _
                              Key .A = x.Item("A").ToString, _
                              Key .B = x.Item("B").ToString _
                             } _
                    )
```

EDIT: The `Key` part means that property is a key for the anonymous type. See the [VB anonymous types MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) for more details.

Comment: If we do not define key then how the hashcode or equality is evaluated  ?

Comment: From the linked document: "An instance of an anonymous types that has no key properties is equal only to itself."