# VB.NET linq group by with anonymous types not working as expected

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, immutability, linqpad

I was toying around with some of the linq samples that come with LINQPad.  In the "C# 3.0 in a Nutshell" folder, under Chater 9 - Grouping, there is a sample query called "Grouping by Multiple Keys".  It contains the following query:

```
from n in new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" }.AsQueryable()
group n by new
{
    FirstLetter = n[0],
    Length = n.Length
}
```

I added the string "Jon" to the end of the array to get an actual grouping, and came up with the following result:

[image: C# LINQPad result]

This was exactly what I was expecting.  Then, in LINQPad, I went to the VB.NET version of the same query:

```
' Manually added "Jon"
from n in new string() { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay", "Jon" }.AsQueryable() _
group by ng = new with _
{ _
    .FirstLetter = n(0), _
    .Length = n.Length _
} into group
```

The result does not properly group Jay/Jon together.

[image: VB.NET LINQPad result]

After pulling my hair out for a bit, I discovered [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) discussing VB.NET anonymous types.  In VB.NET they are mutable by default as opposed to C# where they are  immutable.  In VB, you need to add the `Key` keyword to make them immutable.  So, I changed the query to this (notice the addition of `Key`):

```
from n in new string() { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay", "Jon" }.AsQueryable() _
group by ng = new with _
{ _
    Key .FirstLetter = n(0), _
    Key .Length = n.Length _
} into group
```

This gave me the correct result:

[image]

So my question is this:

1. Why does mutability/immutability of anonymous types matter when linq does an equality comparison?  Notably, in Linq-to-SQL it doesn't matter at all, which is likely just a product of the translation to SQL.  But in Linq-to-objects it apparently makes all the difference.
2. Why would MS have chosen to make VB's anonymous types mutable.  I see no real advantage, and after mucking around with this issue I see some very real disadvantages.  Namely that your linq queries can have subtle bugs.

-- EDIT --

Just an interesting extra piece of info... Apparently this is keyed property issue is widely known.  I just didn't know what to Google for.  It's been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556077/distinct-in-linq-with-anonymous-types-in-vb-net) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626935/why-group-by-key-of-anonymous-objects-does-not-behave-the-way-expected) on stackoverflow.  Here's another example of the issue using anonymous types and Distinct:

```
Dim items = New String() {"a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"}
Dim result = items.Select(Function(x) New With {.MyValue = x}).Distinct()
Dim result2 = items.Select(Function(x) New With {Key .MyValue = x}).Distinct()
'Debug.Assert(result.Count() = 3) ' Nope... it's 6!
Debug.Assert(result2.Count() = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been working around this problem for over a year now, and all my Grouping code is bastardized to fix this weirdness. I just knocked up a sample to demonstrate this problem and try to find a cure, but this appears to be the solution. Adding the 'Key' keyword is the solution. I've put the code on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/pa7KjZv2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Key` modifier doesn't just affect mutability - it also affects the behaviour of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Only `Key` properties are included in those calculations... which clearly affects grouping etc.

As for why it's different for VB - I don't know. It seems odd to me too. I know *I'm* glad that C# works the way it does though :) Even if it could be argued that making properties *optionally* mutable makes sense, I don't see why it should be the default.